# Troubles connecting thread and sending a signal

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

My code below works but after a few times of ending the program and starting it again, the line

```
thread.started.connect(worker.work)
```

doesn't run and the files do not get sent to the GUI. Here is a breakdown of the problem:

Here is the usual results from the terminal when I send two hdf5 files to the folder:

```
running API pyqt5
using configuration at imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/image_analyzer.conf
no Pyro installed. Use dummy event handler.
{'coordinates': True, '_actions': {'home': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235a60>, 'back': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235af0>, 'forward': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235b80>, 'pan': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235ca0>, 'zoom': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235dc0>, 'configure_subplots': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235d30>, 'edit_parameters': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235ee0>, 'save_figure': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f868123f040>}, 'locLabel': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLabel object at 0x7f8681235f70>, 'canvas': <qimageanalyser.mplwidget.MplCanvas object at 0x7f8688935940>, '_nav_stack': <matplotlib.cbook.Stack object at 0x7f868123d850>, '_lastCursor': <Cursors.POINTER: 1>, '_id_press': 2, '_id_release': 3, '_id_drag': 4, '_pan_info': None, '_zoom_info': None, 'mode': <_Mode.NONE: ''>}
try to connect to event service ...
h5 file <test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/2021_08_10_13_43_29 (3rd copy).hdf5> is locked, retrying 1/350
h5 file <test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/2021_08_10_13_43_29 (3rd copy).hdf5> is locked, retrying 2/350
h5 file <test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/2021_08_10_13_43_29 (3rd copy).hdf5> is locked, retrying 3/350
h5 file <test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/2021_08_10_13_43_29 (3rd copy).hdf5> is locked, retrying 4/350
h5 file <test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/2021_08_10_13_43_29 (3rd copy).hdf5> is locked, retrying 5/350
finished run test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/2021_08_10_13_43_29 (3rd copy).hdf5 2021_08_10_13_43_29 (3rd copy).hdf5
<HDF5 file "2021_08_10_13_43_29 (3rd copy).hdf5" (mode r+)>
analyze_image
xmean 135.47
xstd 41.31
xmean 148.42
xstd 41.17
mass:  3.81923985318e-26 [kg] size:  0.0002074740400778919 [m] tof:  0.01 [s]
mass:  3.81923985318e-26 [kg] size:  0.000122395198908796 [m] tof:  0.01 [s]
h5 file <test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/2021_08_10_13_43_29 (4th copy).hdf5> is locked, retrying 1/350
h5 file <test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/2021_08_10_13_43_29 (4th copy).hdf5> is locked, retrying 2/350
h5 file <test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/2021_08_10_13_43_29 (4th copy).hdf5> is locked, retrying 3/350
h5 file <test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/2021_08_10_13_43_29 (4th copy).hdf5> is locked, retrying 4/350
h5 file <test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/2021_08_10_13_43_29 (4th copy).hdf5> is locked, retrying 5/350
finished run test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/2021_08_10_13_43_29 (4th copy).hdf5 2021_08_10_13_43_29 (4th copy).hdf5
<HDF5 file "2021_08_10_13_43_29 (4th copy).hdf5" (mode r+)>
analyze_image
xmean 135.47
xstd 41.31
xmean 148.42
xstd 41.17
mass:  3.81923985318e-26 [kg] size:  0.0002074740400778919 [m] tof:  0.01 [s]
mass:  3.81923985318e-26 [kg] size:  0.000122395198908796 [m] tof:  0.01 [s]
```

But once I end the program and then restart it, perhaps the 3rd-5th time the connection doesn't go through and here are the results disregarding how many attempts I make on sending new hdf5 files to the folder:

```
running API pyqt5
using configuration at imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/image_analyzer.conf
no Pyro installed. Use dummy event handler.
{'coordinates': True, '_actions': {'home': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235a60>, 'back': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235af0>, 'forward': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235b80>, 'pan': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235ca0>, 'zoom': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235dc0>, 'configure_subplots': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235d30>, 'edit_parameters': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f8681235ee0>, 'save_figure': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f868123f040>}, 'locLabel': <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLabel object at 0x7f8681235f70>, 'canvas': <qimageanalyser.mplwidget.MplCanvas object at 0x7f8688935940>, '_nav_stack': <matplotlib.cbook.Stack object at 0x7f868123d850>, '_lastCursor': <Cursors.POINTER: 1>, '_id_press': 2, '_id_release': 3, '_id_drag': 4, '_pan_info': None, '_zoom_info': None, 'mode': <_Mode.NONE: ''>}
try to connect to event service ...
```

And finally here is the code of the program that's affected by this. I am using Pycharm and the `thread.started.connect(worker.work)`, specifically the word `connect` is highlighted and the warning message is `Cannot find reference 'connect' in 'function | pyqtBoundSignal'` :

```
thread = QThread(parent=self)  # this part is in the DesignerMainWindow() __init__() shown below
print('try to connect to event service ...')
worker = watchdog_search.Worker("/home/test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/")
worker.moveToThread(thread)
thread.started.connect(worker.work)
thread.start()
worker.new_file.connect(self.on_finished_run)


def run_app():
    try:
        # first try to get an existing app
        app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
        reuseapp = True
        if app is None:
            app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
            reuseapp = False
    except:
        pass
    dmw = DesignerMainWindow()
    dmw.show()
    return dmw, app, reuseapp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dmw, app, reuseapp = run_app()
    if "app" in globals() and not reuseapp:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the watchdog_search file. Note here also the `emit` in `self.new_file.emit(event.src_path, os.path.basename(event.src_path))` is highlighted and the warning is `Cannot find reference 'emit' in 'pyqtSignal | pyqtSignal'`:

```
import time
import traceback
import os

import h5py
import queue
from typing import Union

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler, DirCreatedEvent, FileCreatedEvent

from .tools.qt import QtCore

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    QObject,
    QThread,
    pyqtSignal,
    pyqtSlot,
)

class NewFileHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self, q, *a, **k):
        super().__init__(*a, **k)
        self._q = q

    def on_created(self, event):
        self._q.put(event)

class Worker(QObject):

    new_file = pyqtSignal(str,str)

    def __init__(self, path):
        super().__init__()
        self._q = queue.Queue()
        observer = Observer()
        handler = NewFileHandler(self._q)
        observer.schedule(handler, path=path, recursive=True)
        # starts a background thread! Thus we need to wait for the
        # queue to receive the events in work.
        observer.start()

    def work(self):
        while True:
            event = self._q.get()
            max_retry_count = 350  # for test purposes now but want to set an upper bound on verifying a file is
            # finished.
            retry_interval_seconds = .01  # every hundreth it will try the file to see if it finished writing
            retry_count = 0
            if event.event_type == "created" and event.src_path.lower().endswith(".hdf5"):
                while True:
                    try:
                        file = h5py.File(event.src_path, "r")
                        file.close()
                    except OSError:
                        if retry_count < max_retry_count:
                            retry_count += 1
                            print(f"h5 file <{event.src_path}> is locked, retrying {retry_count}/{max_retry_count}")
                            time.sleep(retry_interval_seconds)
                        else:
                            print(f"h5 file <{event.src_path}> reached max retry count, skipping")
                            break  # <--- looks useful here
                    except Exception as err:
                        print(f"Got unexpected Error <{type(err).__name__}> while opening <{event.src_path}> ")
                        traceback.print_exc()
                    else:
                        self.new_file.emit(event.src_path, os.path.basename(event.src_path))
                        break
```

Comment: @musicamante no. I am already executing the time consuming tasks in another thread.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I switched to the wrong tab and tagged your post as duplicate instead of another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using Daemon threading:

```
    worker = watchdog_search.Worker("/home/test_image_analyzer_files/Test_Data/")
    worker.new_file.connect(self.on_finished_run)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker.work)
    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread.start()
```